# How to use processed data in next if else statment in omnet++?

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++

In omnet++, i have execute if statement and obtain a value say x, now how to use this value in next else, for example;

```
if(m==1)
x=rl;
elseif(r==1)
use x here
elseif(n==1)
use x here
```

any method such as function etc to retrieve this variable and use here.

Comment: In every programming language I know, if `else if` is being executed it means that `if` part was **not** executed.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen in my case first if execute and get x value then i want to use this x value in elseif

Comment: Change the `else if` to just `if`.

Comment: @Eljay its also not working and given me garbage value

Comment: What is the input?  What is the garbage value output?  What do you mean by "not working"?  Can you provide a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem, rather than the pseudo-code which does not demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a value in the *else* branch that was acquired in *then* branch. The essence of the if/else construct is that ONLY one of the branch is executed. This is neither OMNeT++ specific nor C++ specific.

So in short, you cannot and also should not.